# NativeCommandError when mounting a file share in an Azure VM using net use

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, virtual-machine, fileshare

I followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal) and was able to start up the VM.

Now I’m trying to mount a file share so that I can add files from the dashboard using this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files).

I did the `Connect` command on the Windows virtual machine’s powershell:

```
net use c \\userone.file.core.windows.net\windows /u:AZURE\userone 761lb852i305joijOIJAOIJWOIVJWAORIJVklmvlkmlksrvjjksss5Djt2yJnFcS0Lg7i1fO3iY4u+rS7ti9ct5g1RlERCSPzC9nQ==
```

and `c` so that I want the files to be shared on that drive on the virtual machine.

But I got the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\userwindow>  net use c \\userone.file.core.windows.net\windows /u:AZURE\userone 761lb852i305joijOIJAOIJWOIVJWAORIJVklmvlkmlksrvjjksss5Djt2yJnFcS0Lg7i1fO3iY4u+rS7ti9ct5g1RlERCSPzC9nQ==

net : The syntax of this command is:
At line:1 char:2
+  net use c \\userone.file.core.windows.net\windows /u:AZURE\user ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The syntax of this command is::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]
NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME
NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the drive letter using a *double point*:

```
net use c: \\userone.file.core.windows.net\windows /u:AZURE\userone 761lb852i305joijOIJAOIJWOIVJWAORIJVklmvlkmlksrvjjksss5Djt2yJnFcS0Lg7i1fO3iY4u+rS7ti9ct5g1RlERCSPzC9nQ==
```

**Note**: You probably want to use a different drive letter since c: is already in use!

Comment: Oddly, in the example they provide, they did it without the double point for reason. Also, it is a brand new Windows VM, how can it be in use? And what does it mean to be in use already? Would really want to mount the file share there. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @JoKo windows use c: for OS disk by default, so you should use other drive letter, like Z. In the official article, we can find the example like this`net use z: \\samples.file.core.windows.net\logs /u:AZURE\samples <storage-account-key>`